# create dynamic column name at runtime - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am maintaining a table called store

In my **models.py**

```
 class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=225,null=True,blank=True)
    brand_key = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank= True)
```

I have a store info table where i store each info of store details in the below table

```
class store_info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand_info = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    brand_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I need to create a custom field when adding a new store every time by the name of store. for example if i add lenovo as my **store** as name i have to add a lenovo_status as a field in my **store_info** table.

Does Django has an option for creating custom field in run time? Please help me with some ideas how to create the field in dynamic way.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: XY problem ? Please explain your _REAL_ problem, not what you thinks is the solution.

Comment: whenever a store is created i should add a store status for each store. with that specified store name. Since some of the brand parts are same in that parts we choose. so we have to match the specified part with that brand using the status.